# How to implement item reorder/shuffle animations with Angular's ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

Vue users are easy to implement such item shuffle animations, see their official docs:

[image: shuffle animation]

I search a lot but can't find a solution for Angular users. `ngFor` seems to switch item contents instead of moving items when shuffling them.

Here's my demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/3IcKcC/

When you click shift, you should see items move animation thanks to `li {transform: all 1s;}`. But when you shuffle them, there's no animation. So I'm here asking for a solution.

Comment: Vue official docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions

Comment: Have you read about Angular Animate? It is what you can use to help transition those changes.

Comment: `When you click shift, you should see items move animation thanks to li {transform: all 1s;}`  I would say thanks to vue `transition-group` that does all work

Comment: @frosty Yes I read through the docs. But the docs only points out how to animate transitions from one defined state to another. In this case, items are shuffled and ngFor reorder them, and I can't define the states where ngFor starts to move them and done. I even known nothing about ngFor's reorder logic, does it move items or just switch data context? Could you help me?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is simple implementation such functionality **[Plunker Example](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/i2hRcrTHLxTKA7mk)**

1) Build directives

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[transition-group-item]'
})
export class TransitionGroupItemDirective {
  prevPos: any;

  newPos: any;

  el: HTMLElement;

  moved: boolean;

  moveCallback: any;

  constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: '[transition-group]',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class TransitionGroupComponent {
  @Input('transition-group') class;

  @ContentChildren(TransitionGroupItemDirective) items: QueryList<TransitionGroupItemDirective>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.refreshPosition('prevPos');
    this.items.changes.subscribe(items => {
      items.forEach(item => {
        item.prevPos = item.newPos || item.prevPos;
      });

      items.forEach(this.runCallback);
      this.refreshPosition('newPos');
      items.forEach(this.applyTranslation);

      // force reflow to put everything in position
      const offSet = document.body.offsetHeight;
      this.items.forEach(this.runTransition.bind(this));
    })
  }

  runCallback(item: TransitionGroupItemDirective) {
    if(item.moveCallback) {
      item.moveCallback();
    }
  }

  runTransition(item: TransitionGroupItemDirective) {
    if (!item.moved) {
      return;
    }
    const cssClass = this.class + '-move';
    let el = item.el;
    let style: any = el.style;
    el.classList.add(cssClass);
    style.transform = style.WebkitTransform = style.transitionDuration = '';
    el.addEventListener('transitionend', item.moveCallback = (e: any) => {
      if (!e || /transform$/.test(e.propertyName)) {
        el.removeEventListener('transitionend', item.moveCallback);
        item.moveCallback = null;
        el.classList.remove(cssClass);
      }
    });
  }

  refreshPosition(prop: string) {
    this.items.forEach(item => {
      item[prop] = item.el.getBoundingClientRect();
    });
  }

  applyTranslation(item: TransitionGroupItemDirective) {
    item.moved = false;
    const dx = item.prevPos.left - item.newPos.left;
    const dy = item.prevPos.top - item.newPos.top;
    if (dx || dy) {
      item.moved = true;
      let style: any = item.el.style;
      style.transform = style.WebkitTransform = 'translate(' + dx + 'px,' + dy + 'px)';
      style.transitionDuration = '0s';
    }
  }
}
```

2) Use it as follows

```
<ul [transition-group]="'flip-list'">
  <li *ngFor="let item of items" transition-group-item>
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are so smart, that's the answer I need. Briefly in summary, revert the items' previous position when they are shuffled (in zero seconds), and then animate it to the final position.

Comment: This looks great unless the component being animated isn't fully on the screen. Then the animation is all over the place.

Comment: @yurzui In production animation not working. In debugging i found that class `flip-list-move` persist.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies did you solve it in production? I have the same issue, works in local, but not in production because the class is not removed

Comment: @cucuru Yes i used below answer of user `pawel` and it's working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706664/7561290

Comment: Where the items come from? Do you have a full fledged code for this on your git?

Comment: @CodingbyRaj I've updated plunker https://next.plnkr.co/edit/i2hRcrTHLxTKA7mk Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks @yurzui. New link is working fine and It helps me a lot.

Comment: @CodingbyRaj The OP uses lodash in his example so it's required here. But if you don't want to import it I've updated plunker https://next.plnkr.co/edit/i2hRcrTHLxTKA7mk

Comment: Okay @yurzui, Now working fine on my code but without animation. I am trying to solve it.

Comment: The plunkr doesn't work anymore due to the dependencies failing...

Comment: `unpkg.com` seems to be returning 404s, so the Plunker is broken.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my version of @yurzui code. Changes:

- supports insert and deletion of items
- a forced reflow survives webpack optimizations

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, Directive, ElementRef, Input, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[transition-group-item]'
})
export class TransitionGroupItemDirective {
    prevPos: any;
    newPos: any;
    el: HTMLElement;
    moved: boolean;
    moveCallback: any;

    constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
        this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: '[transition-group]',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class TransitionGroupComponent {
    @Input('transition-group') class;

    @ContentChildren(TransitionGroupItemDirective) items: QueryList<TransitionGroupItemDirective>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => this.refreshPosition('prevPos'), 0); // save init positions on next 'tick'

        this.items.changes.subscribe(items => {
            items.forEach(item => item.prevPos = item.newPos || item.prevPos);
            items.forEach(this.runCallback);
            this.refreshPosition('newPos');
            items.forEach(item => item.prevPos = item.prevPos || item.newPos); // for new items

            const animate = () => {
                items.forEach(this.applyTranslation);
                this['_forceReflow'] = document.body.offsetHeight; // force reflow to put everything in position
                this.items.forEach(this.runTransition.bind(this));
            }

            const willMoveSome = items.some((item) => {
                const dx = item.prevPos.left - item.newPos.left;
                const dy = item.prevPos.top - item.newPos.top;
                return dx || dy;
            });

            if (willMoveSome) {
                animate();
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => { // for removed items
                    this.refreshPosition('newPos');
                    animate();
                }, 0);
            }
        })
    }

    runCallback(item: TransitionGroupItemDirective) {
        if (item.moveCallback) {
            item.moveCallback();
        }
    }

    runTransition(item: TransitionGroupItemDirective) {
        if (!item.moved) {
            return;
        }
        const cssClass = this.class + '-move';
        let el = item.el;
        let style: any = el.style;
        el.classList.add(cssClass);
        style.transform = style.WebkitTransform = style.transitionDuration = '';
        el.addEventListener('transitionend', item.moveCallback = (e: any) => {
            if (!e || /transform$/.test(e.propertyName)) {
                el.removeEventListener('transitionend', item.moveCallback);
                item.moveCallback = null;
                el.classList.remove(cssClass);
            }
        });
    }

    refreshPosition(prop: string) {
        this.items.forEach(item => {
            item[prop] = item.el.getBoundingClientRect();
        });
    }

    applyTranslation(item: TransitionGroupItemDirective) {
        item.moved = false;
        const dx = item.prevPos.left - item.newPos.left;
        const dy = item.prevPos.top - item.newPos.top;
        if (dx || dy) {
            item.moved = true;
            let style: any = item.el.style;
            style.transform = style.WebkitTransform = 'translate(' + dx + 'px,' + dy + 'px)';
            style.transitionDuration = '0s';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey. Trying to use your code ``` items = [9,3,2,4,7,1]``` the after a timeout I am appending 5 but nothing happen. I am trying to have a look to the plunker provided but it is blocked at loading step... I am supposed to declare my list like what yurzui showed ?

Comment: Any idea how to make it scroll aware?

Comment: this line is giving error  -> this['_forceReflow'] = document.body.offsetHeight;

Answer (score 6):

More correct (and TSLint-compliant) would be to use a different Directive name, as:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appTransitionGroupItem]'
})
```

and using a component as an element and not overloading the input name:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-transition-group',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class TransitionGroupComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @Input() className;
```

Which gives the code better Angular structure, my compliant, better read (YMMV) code, being:

```
<app-transition-group [className]="'flip-list'">
  <div class="list-items" *ngFor="let item of items" appTransitionGroupItem>
  etc
```

Also, if you're wondering why the transition animation isn't working, don't forget the CSS required:

```
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Once the animated elements are not in the view the animation breaks.
I fixed it by editing refreshPosition function:

```
refreshPosition(prop: string) {
  this.items.forEach(item => {
    item[prop] = {
      top: item.el.offsetTop,
      left: item.el.offsetLeft
    }
  });
}
```

Originally @yurzui used el.getBoundingClientRect() to get the positions but this method returns positions relative to the viewport.

I changed it so it gets the positions using el.offsetTop and el.offsetLeft which are relative to the first ancestor that isn't positioned 'static'.

Answer (score 2):

You can get pretty close to the desired effect by using CSS `transforms` combined with Angular `trackBy`. The trick is to use the `trackBy` function to persist the HTML element between list position changes.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mmqr3f?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[image]

```js
@Component()
class AppComponent {
  arr = [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { id: 3 },
    { id: 4 },
    { id: 5 },
    { id: 6 },
    { id: 7 }
  ];

  shuffle() {
    this.arr = shuffle(this.arr);
  }

  transform(index: number) {
    return `translateY(${(index + 1) * 100}%)`;
  }

  trackBy(index, x) {
    return x.id;
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="shuffle()">Shuffle</button>
<div class="container">
  <div
    class="list-item"
    *ngFor="let obj of arr; index as index; trackBy: trackBy"
    [style.transform]="transform(index)"
  >
    id: {{ obj.id }}
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.list-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: coral;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: if you want another aproach using Angular animations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739771/animate-the-position-of-two-or-more-div-positions-in-angular/62744780#62744780

Comment: This is actually pretty cool though it does assume the elements are all the same height

Comment: great idea, but curious why some of them just blink to new position while others actually animate, any idea?