# How to change angular ngfor element order with animation

Tags: angular, sorting, animation, grid

when the user inputs any number in element (grid) I want to sort that element (grid) on entered number position with animation in bubble manner.

example: if the user enters number 2 on the element that is currently in position 5th  then element move from position 5th to 4th then 4th to 3rd then 3rd to 2nd position with animation(like automatically drag till desire position).

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes I tried from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928524/how-to-implement-item-reorder-shuffle-animations-with-angulars-ngfor 

it works in fiddle but not working in project

Answer (score 1):

The post is 3 years old. But here is a library which can sort a grid. You can check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/Flo0806/ngx-explorer-dnd). There is a animation included so you can see how this thing will work.

But short: You need to animate the items by yourself; calculate the position (old and new), create a deep cloned element and set a transition animation to it. If the animation done change the array with the items.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wsegkg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example for the library.

Otherwise you can use a `FlexBox` and sort the items in the array (`*ngFor`) with this method for example:

```
export function moveItemInArray<T = any>(
  array: T[],
  fromIndex: number,
  toIndex: number
): void {
  const from = clamp(fromIndex, array.length - 1);
  const to = clamp(toIndex, array.length - 1);

  console.log(from, to);
  if (from === to) {
    return;
  }

  const target = array[from];
  const delta = to < from ? -1 : 1;

  for (let i = from; i !== to; i += delta) {
    array[i] = array[i + delta];
  }

  array[to] = target;
}
```