# Animate the position of two or more DIV positions in Angular

Tags: angular

I need help to anymate the position switch of 2 or more divs dynamically rendered.
Here is a simple example:

```
let objects: Array<number> = [];
objects.push(1);
objects.push(2);
```

The template:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of objects">
    content {{object}}
</div>
```

From the template the user can change the position of object, moving the object "1" to the second position, and the object "2" will become the first one.

I need an animation to expose clearly the movent to the user. Actually the result in DOM is this one:

Before:

```
<div>
   content 1
</div>
<div>
  content 2
</div>
```

After:

```
<div>
   content 2
</div>
<div>
  content 1
</div>
```

The result is obtained modifying the source Array, changing the elements position.

Which solution could I use? I can use more complex objects to handle this so I can modify the code if it's needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's a good solution, but is the only I can imagine. My idea is has a "copy" of the divs with position absolute maintain the "originals" with opacity=0 or visivility=hidden. When change the array, enclosed in a setTimeout make a manual animation changing the top and left of the "copy".

In code. Imagine you has an array data

```
data:any[]=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

An html like

```
<div >
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data;let i=index">
    <div #origin style="opacity:0" >{{item}}</div>
    <div #copy  style="position:absolute" [style.z-index]="i" >{{item}}</div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

And we get in a ViewChildren the "origin" and the "copy" in a ngAfterViewInit we position the "copy" in his position

```
 @ViewChildren("origin") bars: QueryList<ElementRef>;
 @ViewChildren("copy") copies: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    const bars:any[]=this.bars.toArray().map(x=>x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect());
    this.copies.forEach((x,index) => {
      x.nativeElement.style.top=bars[index].top+"px"
      x.nativeElement.style.left=bars[index].left+"px"
    });
  }
```

Well, in a click, I reorder the array and make the animation

```
  click() {
    this.data=this.data
               .map(x=>({item:x,value:Math.random()}))
               .sort((a,b)=>a.value-b.value)
               .map(x=>x.item)

    setTimeout(()=>{
        const bars:any[]=this.bars.toArray().map 
           (x=>x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect());
        this.copies.forEach((x,index) => {
           this.animate(x.nativeElement, bars[index].top+"px",bars[index].left+"px");
        });
    })
  }
  animate(element: any, top: string,left:string) {
    const myAnimation = this.builder.build([
      animate(this.timing, style({ top: top,left:left }))
    ]);
    this.player = myAnimation.create(element);
    this.player.play();
  }
```

You can see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s4nw4h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Update** Why not make a directive?

**Update 2** I update the directive using offsetTop and offsetLeft and adding window.scrollX and window.scrollY. Futhermore I added a new property: pos0, if true, at first the "copy" create in pos 0,0

```
@Directive({ selector: "[animate]" })
export class AnimateDirective implements OnInit {
  original: any;
  copy: any;
  timing:string;
  private player: AnimationPlayer;

  @Input() set animate(value: string) {
    this.timing = value || "450ms ease-in-out";
  }
  @Input('animatePos0') pos0:boolean=false;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private builder: AnimationBuilder,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.original = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
      this.templateRef
    ).rootNodes[0];
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.copy = this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(
        this.templateRef
      ).rootNodes[0];
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.original, "visibility","hidden");
      const rect = !this.pos0?
          {top:this.original.offsetTop,left:this.original.offsetLeft}:
          {top:0,left:0};
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.copy, "position", "absolute");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.copy, "top", rect.top+ window.scrollY + "px");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.copy, "left", rect.left+ window.scrollX + "px");
    });
  }
  animateGo() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const rect = {top:this.original.offsetTop,left:this.original.offsetLeft}
      const myAnimation = this.builder.build([
        animate(this.timing, 
          style({ top: rect.top+ window.scrollY, 
                  left: rect.left+ window.scrollX }))
      ]);
      this.player = myAnimation.create(this.copy);
      this.player.play();
    });
  }
}
```

Well, we need has some like

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data;let i=index">
<div *animate="'150ms ease-in-out'"> {{item}}-{{i}}
</div>
</ng-container>
```

And in our component a ViewChildren

```
@ViewChildren(AnimateDirective) items:QueryList<AnimateDirective>
```

So, when we change the data we need make

```
this.items.forEach(x=>x.animateGo())
```

See a [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xv78gq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fanimate.directive.ts)

Comment: This solution is brillant, I like it!

Comment: @Pennywise83, be carefully I forget add the window.scrollX and window.scrollY. And I don't prety sure if use getBoundClientRec or offsetTop and ofsetLeft of the original. In any case I have difficult with the "margin" of the object. I'm not pretty sure to correct this on time. I improve a few the stackblitz with this and adding a new property "pos0" for "animate" when add

Answer (score -1):

the best solution after my research was to use the **cdk/drag-drop** You can import this library and can use it for dragging and dropping the elements.

You just have to add the following lines in your code and it would work fine.

Your .ts file should contain the following code.

```
export class CdkDragDropSortingExample {
  movies = [
    'Episode I - The Phantom Menace',
    'Episode II - Attack of the Clones'
  ];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

Your html should be:

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let movie of movies" cdkDrag>{{movie}}</div>
</div>
```

Your css file should contain following classes:

```
.example-list {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.example-box {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: move;
  background: white;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.cdk-drag-preview {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
              0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
              0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.cdk-drag-animating {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.example-box:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.example-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .example-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
  transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```