# Is there an Angular version of the React-flip-move library?

Tags: angular, animation, flexbox

I didn't find any equivalent in order to animate flexbox, in particular when elements are wrapped and jump to the next line. Thank you

Comment: some like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739771/animate-the-position-of-two-or-more-div-positions-in-angular/62744780#62744780)? Really I don't know if is a good aproach :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are 3rd party libaries out that that fit your need, but none come to mind at this time. However if you don't find anything perhaps this could help you: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-custom-placeholder

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  My goal here is to animate a flexbox list of elements with flex-wrap: wrap;   where some elements enter, others leave, and some elements are translated from one line to another. How would I do this with CdkDropList?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package "Animations on enter / on leave"
**https://github.com/filipows/angular-animations#readme**

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31629541)