How to animate flex items position changes with angular animations
I'm trying to create a smooth animation when an item is removed or changed it's location in a flex layout with angular animations. I've clean playground.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-list-animations-tmkpdc
My problem is I cannot really figure out how to use angular animation to do it.
Thanks

It's a bit old, but as inspiration... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739771/animate-the-position-of-two-or-more-div-positions-in-angular/62744780#62744780

Thanks, certainly helps, I hoped it could be done with coding, but I guess its not really supported as I imagined.

The fully animated solution is possible only when it's a horizontally stacked list (the container dimensions do not change the number of elements per line) which is not the case in your code.
My solution is to simple set the transition: order 1s so that the order changes triggers a animation of shuffling of reds, it's simple but it's still better than nothing:
<!-- list.component.html -->
<h2>Angular Animations In Lists</h2>
<button (click)="removeFirst()"> Remove first element</button>
<button (click)="randomizeOrder()"> Randomize order</button>

<div [@listAnimation]="items.length"
    (@listAnimation.start)="logAnimation($event)"
    (@listAnimation.done)="logAnimation($event)"
    class="container" style="display: flex;"
>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" [style.order]="item.order" [class.red]="item.value %2 == 0" [style.height]="'70px'" [style.width]="'70px'" style="transition: order 1s;" >
    {{ item.value }}
  </div>
</div>

Stackblitz Demo
